# On the exactness of the restriction to small etale site in the case of differentiable stacks

Tags: sheaf-cohomology, differentiable-stacks

Let $X$ be a manifold considered as a stack on the big etale site of manifolds. Consider the functor $$ F \mapsto F_X$$ which sends a sheaf on the stack $X$ to the sheaf on the manifold $X$.
In Lemma 3.4 (on page 19), [Behrend and Xu](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0605694.pdf) say it is a "fact" that the above functor is exact. Why is this true? A reference is also acceptable.

Comment: This functor is induced by restricting from the big site of X to the small site of X.  The sheaf condition only uses open embeddings in its formulation, i.e., morphisms in the small site.  Thus, the restriction functor is a left adjoint functor of a geometric morphism, so necessarily preserves finite homotopy limits and finite homotopy colimits.

Comment: I do not understand the last sentence. Why is the restriction functor a left adjoint of a geometric morphism? It is hard for me to imagine a functor that constructs a sheaf on the big site from a sheaf on the small site. Can you kindly tell me what it looks like?